# Returning false from Equals methods without Overriding

Tags: java

Write `TestEquals class` so that main method of `Puzzle3` class prints `false`.

> Note: You cannot override equals method of TestEquals class.

```
public class Puzzle3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestEquals testEquals = new TestEquals();
        System.out.println(testEquals.equals(testEquals));
    }
}
```

I didn't find a way to achieve this, please share your comments

Comment: *"please share your comments"* This is not a question.

Comment: sounds like homework, or a test

Comment: This would be the *Java Puzzlers* by Joshua Bloch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not override the equals method, but there is no reason you cannot overload the equals method.

The method Object.equals has prototype:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) { ... }
```

To override this method you have to create a method with the same prototype in TestEquals.  However your problem statement indicates that you are not allowed to override this method.  No problem, overloading the method is a valid approach to accomplish your task.  Simply add the following method definition to TestEquals:

```
public boolean equals(TestEquals o) { return false; }
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of *overriding* equals you can *overload* equals

```
class TestEquals {
    // a common mistake which doesn't override equals(Object)
    public boolean equals(TestEquals te) { 
          return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Following would print false :)**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class TestEquals {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestEquals testEquals = new TestEquals();
    System.out.println(testEquals.equals(testEquals));
  }

  static {
    System.setOut(new CustomPrintStream(new PrintStream(System.out)));
  }

  public static class CustomPrintStream extends PrintStream {

    /**
     * This does the trick.
     */
    @Override
      public void println(boolean x) {
      super.println(!x);
    }

    public CustomPrintStream(File file, String csn) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
      super(file, csn);
    }

    public CustomPrintStream(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
      super(file);
    }

    public CustomPrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush, String encoding)
      throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
      super(out, autoFlush, encoding);
    }

    public CustomPrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
      super(out, autoFlush);
    }

    public CustomPrintStream(OutputStream out) {
      super(out);
    }

    public CustomPrintStream(String fileName, String csn) throws FileNotFoundException,
                                                                 UnsupportedEncodingException {
      super(fileName, csn);
    }

    public CustomPrintStream(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
      super(fileName);
    }
  }
}
```