# equals to return false

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning false from Equals methods without Overriding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156059/returning-false-from-equals-methods-without-overriding)

One of my colleague asked me a question today as mentioned below

Write TestEquals class(custom or user defined class) so that the below s.o.p in the code prints `false`.

```
public class Puzzle3 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestEquals testEquals = new TestEquals();
    System.out.println(testEquals.equals(testEquals));
  }
}
```

**Note: You cannot override equals method.**

I thought a lot but couldn't find the solution without overriding equals.Does anybody have any idea how it can be done?

Comment: This isn't homework?

Comment: Is **overloading** permitted?

Comment: The duplicate got two downvotes and the accepted answer only four upvotes. What makes the question so much better this time?

Comment: @maba I thought the same. The original question (not this one) is rather harshly worded with no introduction. I guess people are delicate about that sort of thing. Once the question became down-voted, fewer people visit it and presumably the answer gets less up-votes as a result.

Comment: @maba it's odd. It looks like they are both in the same class. Perhaps people are feeling kinder as it is nearing the end of the week...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use

```
public boolean equals(TestEquals equals) {
    return false
}
```

To override equals you need the input parameter to be of type object so the above code snippet theorectially is not overriding equals from the object method

Comment: It could also return a `String` if you felt like it.

Comment: @DuncanJones good point I didnt think of that +1 for pointing that out

Answer (score 11):

EDIT: Apparently [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12158031/20394) arrived at this idea first on another thread, but I'll leave this here since this code is significantly simpler.

---

```
class TestEquals {

  static {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FilterOutputStream(System.out) {
      public void write(byte[] buf, int pos, int len) throws IOException {
        if (len >= 4 && buf[pos] == 't') {
          out.write(new byte[] {
              (byte) 'f', (byte) 'a', (byte) 'l', (byte) 's', (byte) 'e'
            });
          out.write(buf, pos + 4, len - 4);
        } else {
          out.write(buf, pos, len);
        }
      }
    }));
  }
}
```

This horrible hack does not override or overload anything to do with `equals`, but the act of creating an instance of `TestEquals` causes the class to load which wraps `System.out` so that any subsequent print that starts with `'t'` will cause `"false"` to be printed instead of the first 4 bytes.  (Assuming the default encoding is not something super-exotic.)

Comment: +1 for thinking out-of-the box.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you could write a method like so:

```
public boolean equals(TestEquals e) {
    return false;
}
```

In addition, if `TestEquals` can extend some other object:

```
public TestEquals extends Something {
}

public Something {
    @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would anyone want to do that. But you can create a method as shown below :

```
public boolean equals(SuperEquals equals) { return false; }
```

Where `SuperEquals` is any superclass of `TestEquals` but not `Object`.

Answer (score -1):

On my iPad...The Strategy should be something like having aun attribute that is modified every time you do a get on it..this will work if the attribute is accessed through the getter on equals. You mention that equals can not be override so the attribute should be private and the modification of the value happen before and after the value is read, to make sure it works no matter if it is the first or the second part of the equals.

Something like( sorry for any syntax errors):

```
public class TestEquals{

 private int id;

 public int getId(){
    int temp;
    id++;
    temp=id;
    id++;
    return temp;
 }
}
```

Comment: The first check in Object.equals(Object obj) is `if (this == obj) return true`.